# Using Theano with GPU on Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS g2

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, nvidia, theano

I'm having trouble getting Theano to use the GPU on my machine.

When I run:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/misc$ THEANO_FLAGS=floatX=float32,device=gpu python check_blas.py
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available  (error: Unable to get the number of gpus available: no CUDA-capable device is detected)

I've also checked that the NVIDIA driver is installed with: lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12

with result: Kernel driver in use: nvidia

However, when I run: nvidia-smi
result: NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidiactl (No such file or directory).
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with NVIDIA driver. Make sure that latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

and /dev/nvidiaactl doesn't exist. What's going on?

UPDATE: /nvidia-smi works with result:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 4.304...   Driver Version: 304.116        |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     | Bus-Id        Disp.  | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage         | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GRID K520                | 0000:00:03.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   39C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |   0%   10MB / 4095MB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and after compiling the NVIDIA_CUDA-6.0_Samples then running deviceQuery I get result:

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL

Comment: are you running `nvidia-smi` as a root user?  If not, try running as root.  If you are running it as root, your driver is not properly installed.  Try re-installing the driver.  By the way, Ubuntu 14.04 is not officially supported for any CUDA version up through 6.0

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't running it as root.  It worked. 
I'll try with an older version of ubuntu

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 4):

CUDA GPUs in a linux system are not usable until certain "device files" have been properly established.

There is a note to this effect in [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#runfile-verifications).

In general there are several ways these device files can be established:

1. If an X-server is running.
2. If a GPU activity is initiated as root  user (such as running nvidia-smi, or any CUDA app.)
3. Via startup scripts (refer to the documentation linked above for an example).

If none of these steps are taken, the GPUs will not be functional for non-root users.  Note that the files do not persist through re-boots, and must be re-established on each boot cycle, through one of the 3 above methods.  If you use method 2, and reboot, the GPUs will not be available until you use method 2 again.

I suggest reading the linux getting started guide entirely (linked above), if you are having trouble setting up a linux system for CUDA GPU usage.

Comment: So I created a new AWS g2 instance with ubuntu13.10 and tried it again, running nvidia-smi as root, and compiled the samples and when I run deviceQuery I get the error:

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL

Comment: This is a completely different problem of course.  SO Q+A are not intended to be chat sessions.  Why don't you read the documentation I linked?  It indicates what is necessary both to set up a proper CUDA installation and the specific commands to validate each step along the way.  For starters, what driver version is reported when you run `nvidia-smi -a` as root, and what version of CUDA toolkit is installed?

Comment: Thank you for that documentation, I'd actually found it previously and tried to follow the steps, but some of the pre-installation steps hadn't worked for me.  Driver Version: 304.116, CUDA: 6.0

Comment: CUDA 6 will not work with 304.116.  You need to install a driver like 331.62 or newer.  If you actually install the CUDA toolkit (e.g. use the runfile install method described in the documentation) on that platform, rather than trying to bring it in from an AMI or repositories, you will get an appropriate driver.  The best bet is to install a recent driver for the GPUs on that platform, which I think are GRID K520, so something like [this one](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/76884/en-us).  If you are not using GRID K520 or 64-bit linux, then choose an appropriate driver.

Comment: So I tried installing driver 340.42 from the website and directly from the CUDA toolkit, and they both fail with a kernel error. The only way i got it to work is through the steps here: http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/ but nvidia-current was 304, and when I tried 331, 334, and 340 it refuses to pair with my GRID K520

Comment: what was the "kernel error"?  something about "missing kernel headers" or "sources"?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CUDA 7.5, make sure follow official instruction:
CUDA 7.5 doesn't support the default g++ version. Install an supported version and make it the default.

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 10

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 10

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 30
sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 30
sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++
```

If theano GPU test code has error:

> ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu:
>   libcublas.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory  WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but
>   device gpu is not available (error: cuda unavilable)

Just using `ldconfig` command to link the shared object of cuda 7.5:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64
```

Comment: OT: thanks a lot, this ldconfig trick - helped me solve the problem after 2 hours of useless debugging

Answer (score 0):

I've wasted a lot of hours trying to get AWS G2 to work on ubuntu but failed by getting exact error like you did. Currently I'm running Theano with gpu smoothly with [this](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00FYCDDTE) redhat AMI. To install Theano on Redhat follow the process of *Installing Theano in CentOS* in Theano documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and reinstalled Cuda and at the end it says i have to update PATH to include /usr/local/cuda7.0/bin and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include /usr/local/cuda7.0/lib64. The PATH (add LD_LIBRARY_PATH in same file) can be found in /etc/environment. Then theano found gpu. Basic error on my part...

Answer (score 0):

I got

```
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

and my problem is related with the selected GPU mode.
In other words, the problem may be related to the selected GPU mode (Performance/Power Saving Mode), when you select (with nvidia-settings utility, in the "PRIME Profiles" configurations) the integrated Intel GPU and you execute the `deviceQuery` script... you get this error:

But this error is misleading,
by **selecting** back the **NVIDIA(Performance mode)** with **nvidia-settings** utility the  problem disappears.

**This is not a version problem**.

Regards

P.s: The selection is available when Prime-related-stuff is installed. Further details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/858030/nvidia-prime-in-nvidia-x-server-settings-in-16-04-1